# DropDown Menu won't to display on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello guys I have this drop down menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li class="dropDown"><a>DropDown</a>
   <div id="container">
       <div class="col1">
          <h3 class="has3">CheckOn</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
          </ul></div>
        <div class="col1">
         <h3 class="has3">MasterLink</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link8</a></li>
        </ul></div>

    <div class="col1">
                    <h3 class="has3">MasterLink</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link12</a></li>
        </ul></div>

    <div class="col1">
                    <h3 class="has3">MasterLink</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link13</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link14</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link15</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link16</a></li>
        </ul></div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

with this css:

```
#menu{background:#9c7d9e; padding:10px;}

#container{
    width: 550px;
    height: 150;
    border: 1px solid #c5a0b7;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:none;
}

#mainContainer.dropDown:hover ul{
  display: block;
}

.col1{
float:left;
    margin:5px 20px 0px 20px;
    border-right:1px solid #eaeaea;
}

h3{
width:50px;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
margin-bottom:5px;
  }

a{
text-decoration:none;
padding:5px 0;
}
```

Is not an ordinal menu because instead of hidden `ul`, I use a `div` with other `divs` inside that contain `uls` but the behavior should be the same when cursor pass over main `li` from menu should display container `div`

I dont want to change html structure because I need the menu to be designed exactly how it is.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please add a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: It will be good if you provide jsfiddle for this..

Comment: step on the way http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1415/

Comment: shold you add a new comment to give you all points. Thank you.

Comment: it this http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1418/ what you are after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're addressing the wrong element after :hover.
http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1419/

using a div inside an li is frowned upon.

Comment: why the background menu ul is expanding with container div? :|

Comment: Because what you are showing (#container) is inside that element.

Comment: it's actually not. But like  user1141356 said, position:absolute will solve that.

Answer (score 7):

You have to change the `#container` to block instead

http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1416/

Comment: but why the background menu ul is expanding with container div? :|

Answer (score 3):

Replace .col1 with div..

http://jsfiddle.net/8SEma/

Comment: why the background menu ul is expanding with container div? :|