# Third Tier Sublist in Drop Down Menu Won't Display on Hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

Here's the site I'm working on: http://argumentinamerica.com/

The menu goes like this:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Home</a></li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href="#"><span></span>Units</a>
        <ul>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href="#">Unit 1</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Read About It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Write About It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hear About It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Speak About It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Read About It</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Write About It</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href="#">Unit 2</a></li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href="#">Unit 3</a></li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href="#">Unit 4</a></li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href="#">Unit 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Teacher Center</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Give 1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the css is like this:

```
#menu {
margin: 0; padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
list-style-type: none;
height: 2.4em;
}
#menu ul, #menu li, #menu span, #menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#menu li {
float: left;
width: 20%;
}
#menu a {
display: block;
margin: 1px;
height: 2.4em;
font-size: 10px;
line-height: 2.4em;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
background: #ffcc66;
color: #996600;
}
#menu span {
position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 8px;
width: 8px; height: 8px;
background: #ff9933;
}
#menu a:hover {
background: #cc3300;
color: #ffcc66;
}

#menu ul{
list-style-type: none;
}
#menu .has-sub {
    z-index: 1;
}
#menu .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: list-item;
}
#menu .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
}
#menu .has-sub ul li {
    *margin-bottom: -1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.6em;
    line-height: 2.4em;
}
#menu .has-sub ul li a {
    background: #ff9944;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: ffcc66;
}
#menu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
    background: #ff6633;
    color: 993300;
}
#menu .has-sub {
    z-index: 1;
}
#menu .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: list-item;
}
#menu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
}
#menu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
}
#menu .has-sub .has-sub ul li {
    *margin-bottom: -1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.6em;
    line-height: 2.4em;
}
#menu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
    background: #ff9944;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: ffcc66;
}
#menu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu .has-sub .has-sub ul li:hover a {
    background: #ff6633;
    color: 993300;
}
```

The third tier is under Units: Unit 1.

I looked at [Displaying third tier submenus properly with css only menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331212/displaying-third-tier-submenus-properly-with-css-only-menu) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775342/adding-third-tier-to-drop-down-menu and [DropDown Menu won't to display on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800919/dropdown-menu-wont-to-display-on-hover) and a lot of other questions trying to figure out what's wrong, but I still can't get the third tier to display. I would really appreciate someone taking a look and telling me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the CSS which causes the third tier to appear is not correct:
`#menu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }`  In this code the '>' targets an `ul` which is a direct child of a `.has-sub:hover` element - in your HTML the 3rd tier ul is not a child of the `li.has-sub` element.  You could change the > to a +, which means it targets an `ul` element directly following the `li.has-sub` element which for this code causes the third tier to appear.  The next problem is that the third tier items appear directly underneath the second tier, so they need to be moved somewhere - see the example code.

http://codepen.io/nztim/pen/GpbqK

Now you need to get the menu to stay visible when you hover over the third tier, but I'll leave that to you, all the best :)

Comment: Thank you for your help @nzt --obviously, it works.  But that is so mean, I've spent two hours trying to figure out why the third tier won't stay when I try to mouseover.  I know so little about what I'm trying to do that even simple things are so hard for me.  Just the original menu took me 14 hours.  I'm trying to learn--I read about how you apply a hover style to the a element to keep it "hovered" when you move on to its child item, and I think that's what I'm doing, but it's just not working.

Comment: I have some general suggestions that I found really helpful in learning CSS.  I can recommend the Lynda.com CSS courses by James Williamson, I thought they were excellent and way worth a month's subscription on their own.  Also I would suggest using the Chrome developer tools (or equivalent for other browsers), this is how I work on all problems in HTML/CSS including this one.  You can see the structure of the HTML, see what CSS styles are applied to each element, see why things are displayed/not displayed, and actually make changes in the browser and see the result - awesome! Good luck!

Comment: Here is a little tutorial which makes a menu like the one you are working on: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu  Note the structure - that the sub-menus are `ul`s inside the parent item's `li`.